# I need help sending a json string from javascript in a request recieved by php code

Tags: javascript, php, json, request

Fairly new to programming and i cannot figure out anywhere how to do this, or of it's possible this way. I want to be able to insert my javascript array of objects into myphp admin database. I'm trying to pass the objects via json to php code that will receive a request and execute the insert statement. I'm stuck because I Cannot get my php page to receive the request. The code below shows where i'm at.

Javascript function

```
function submitExpenses(){

          var json = JSON.stringify( expenses );

          request= new XMLHttpRequest();

          request.open("POST", "InsertExpense.php", false);

          request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

          request.send(json);

        }
```

InsertExpense.php ...

```
  if ($_REQUEST) //Never receives request
{

  include('/DB/connect_to_database.php');
  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));



 foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
           print "$key => $value\n";
       }

// $sql = "INSERT INTO daily_expense (Amount, Category, Dateof)
// VALUES ()";

// if ($dbh->query($sql) === TRUE) {
//     echo "New record created successfully";
// } else {
//     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $dbh->error;
// }

// $dbh->close();
// }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use vanilla JavaScript? Could you maybe try jQuery? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Did you get any errors in console ?

Comment: No errors in the console. and the submitexpenses method runs. Im just not sure if a request is being sent or received. I will look into jquery. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST  can not parse application/json content-type directly. 
So when you sent content type as application/json all of this three remain null. 
Remove your **if** condition. Instead do the following.

In **InsertExpense.php**

```
 if ($_REQUEST) { // Never full fill the condition because its always null

  echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if ($data) { // successfully retrive data so its become true.
echo json_encode($data);
}
```